# sending bitmap image via email in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, java-me

How could I send the bitmap from a BitmapField to an email address on BlackBerry?

Comment: How did you construct the BitmapField in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not rly sure if this is what you try to accomplish. [Sending an image as attachment](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11935/Send_msg_with_attachment_565471_11.jsp).
If you rly need a `BitmapField` to get the image from, can you extend it to hold the bitmap and implement a getImage method?