# Get byte array from bitmap

Tags: blackberry, java-me, bitmap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [sending bitmap image via email in blackberry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5937775/sending-bitmap-image-via-email-in-blackberry)

I need to send the image from a BitmapField to the server and am wondering how could I get the byte array of that Bitmap Image ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Bitmap](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/Bitmap.html).getARGB(...)  [Bitmap](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/Bitmap.html).getRGB565(...)